# Civicrm - Joomla Backend forms width

Tags: joomla, forms, css, contact-layout-editor

we have just started to use Civi for our organisation, but now we are expieriencing some strange layout problem in the backend.

All the forms seem to have a fixed width, and i have no idea where to change/fix this. I know, this is a noob question, but without CSS-experience, it is hard to figure out where to fix this.

Any hints, please?

Joomla Version: 3.9.8
Civi-Version:5.28 (Problem ist still persisting since, i cannot remember 5.19??)

Thanks a lot!

Gerald[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue... somebody unchecked the box

Disable CiviCRM css in "ressource urls"... Thanks anyway...